# Want to automatically insert current Date in the table When a post Request is made

Tags: date, spring-boot, jpa

I have a User Entity and an Order Entity.
One of the field in order entity is date.
Till now i have the user enter the date.
Now i want that at the time post request is made the date is automatically set to the current date and stored in the database.

Tried using @Prepersist annotation But since this is my first API that i am developing using springBoot , I don't really know how to use it.

User Entity

```
    @Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Name is compulsory")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z-'. ]*[A-Za-z]*$",message = "Name has invalid characters")
    private String username;

    //@NotEmpty(message = "Phone Number is compulsary")
    @Range(min = 6400000000L ,max=9999999999L)
    private Long phoneNumber;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Address is compulsary")
    private String address;

    public User(){}

    public User(BigInteger id, String username, Long phoneNumber, String address) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.address = address;

    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Long getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(Long phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Order Entity

```
 @Entity
public class Orders {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private BigInteger id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
     private Date date;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Orders(){}
    public Orders(BigInteger id, Date date,BigInteger userId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.user=new User(userId," ",0000000000L," ");
    }

    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

Order Controller

```
    @RestController
public class OrdersController {

    @Autowired
    private OrdersService ordersService;

    @ApiOperation(value="Show all orders")
    @RequestMapping("/orders")
    public Iterable<Orders> getAllOrders()
    {
        return ordersService.getAllOrders();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Show a particular Order")
    @RequestMapping("/orders/{orderId}")
    public Orders getOrderById(@PathVariable BigInteger orderId)
    {
        return ordersService.getOrderById(orderId);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Show all orders of a particular User")
    @RequestMapping("/users/{id}/orders")
    public List<Orders> getOrders(@PathVariable BigInteger id) {
        return ordersService.getOrders(id);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Show an order for a User")
    @RequestMapping("/users/{userId}/orders/{id}")
    public Orders getOrder(@PathVariable BigInteger id){
        return ordersService.getOrder(id);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Adds a new Order")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,value = "/users/{userId}/orders")
    public Orders addOrder(@PathVariable BigInteger userId,@RequestBody Orders orders) {
        orders.setUser(new User(userId," ",0000000000L," "));
        return ordersService.addOrder(orders);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Alter an Order")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value="/users/{userId}/orders/{id}")
    public Orders updateOrder(@RequestBody Orders order,@PathVariable BigInteger id,@PathVariable BigInteger userId)throws Exception {
        order.setUser(new User(userId," ",0000000000L," "));
        return ordersService.updateOrder(order, id);
    }

    @ApiOperation(value="Delete an Order")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value="/orders/{id}")
    public void deleteOrder(@PathVariable BigInteger id){
        ordersService.deleteOrder(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@PrePersist` is a JPA annotation and therefore should work in all compatible persistence frameworks. It indicates a method that should be invoked on particular entity lifecycle event. (Other events are well documented in the Hibernate user guide [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks)).

Add this to your entity:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Date timestamp;

@PrePersist
private void onCreate() {
    timestamp = new Date();
}
```

---

As for assigning/creating the entity in the controller, it is a good practice to use DTO (data transfer objects) in your controller (`@RequestBody OrderDto orderDto`) and then use some method to populate a new entity instance with those values. Most common options are

- [modelmapper](https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/)
- manually

  ```
  ...
  Order o = new Order();
  o.user = userDao.findById(orderDto.getUserId());
  ...
  // persist o
  ```

Comment: I need to remove the @RequestBody from the Post method??